# How to trigger another action listener after completion of ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I created a GUI with a `JFrame`, `JPanel`, `JLabel` and a `JButton`.

```
 // JFrame
    Jframe f = new JFrame("");
 
 // JButton
    JButton b = new JButton("button1");

 // JLabel
    JLabel l = new JLabel("panel label");

 // JPanel
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
```

I added the button and the label to the panel. I added two `ActionListener`s for the button.

```
 b.addActionListener(e -> {
          //code
        });
 b.addActionListener(e -> {
          //code
        });
```

I want to execute the first action listener. Then execute the other one.
Basically, I have some text that I want to output in the label, sequentially. I want for it to show "Hello" then "Goodbye" on the panel. The problem that it is giving me, is that it only shows the text from my second `ActionListener` "Goodbye".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert second one to the below sample. The reason it only show the second one because **both runs immediately and you see the last one as label.**

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        // set your label as Goodbye here
                        // add any other business logic
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    
                }
                
            });
            t.start(); 
        }
        
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you explain your code?

Comment: when you add multiple action listeners to a button, all runs synchronous. When we use thread, it doesn't block other functions. Also it runs asynchronous. That **Thread.sleep** makes it wait for a second before running the remaining in the thread block.

Comment: *"That `Thread.sleep` makes it wait for a second .."* It's only by accident that works. Use a Swing `Timer` for reliable functionality.